# 2 threads accepted at the same time

Tags: terminology, automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

Assuming we have an automaton that simultaneously accepts a string on two paths. Would this mean that the construction of the NFA might be faulty?  In other words; at the end of any string over any alphabet, does the NFA have to end up accepting one single path only? Or could it accept several at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by an automaton that simultaneously accepts 2 threads?  What do you mean by "thread" in this context?  I've never heard the word "thread" used in this context.  Do you mean "accepts 2 different input strings"?  Do you mean "has 2 different accepting computations" (or "has 2 different accepting paths")?  What does "simultaneously" and "at the same time" mean here -- are those words extraneous or do they have some particular meaning?  What do you mean by "over any alphabet"?  For a single NFA, the alphabet is fixed.

Comment: @D.W. By "thread" I indeed meant "path"; you have to apologize me as I am just starting to learn about theoretical CS.  What I meant by my question was: Let's assume x = {0,1}* and a = 1; and let's say that "xaa" would be accepted by 2 different accepting states of the same automaton after it has finished reading the entire string, would that be an acceptable outcome?

Answer (score 4):

A NFA is defined so that if there is *any* accepting path for the given input string, it will accept. It's perfectly allowable for an NFA to have two paths to acceptance. If *no* path accepts, then the NFA doesn't accept.

Answer (score 3):

An NFA which has only one accepting path for any string is known as unambiguous. Any regular language can be represented as an unambiguous NFA (since DFAs are, trivially, unambiguous NFAs), but NFAs which are not defined as such are still valid.

The acceptance of an NFA very much corresponds to the $\exists$ quantifier: the string is accepted if there is at least one solution, and more than one is still acceptable.

Comment: In other words:  it would be acceptable--correct me if I am wrong--if  x = {0,1}* and a = 1; and let's say that "xaa" would be accepted by 2 different accepting states of the same automaton after it has finished reading the entire string.  Simply put, after the NFA has finished reading the last character of the input string; it wouldn't be necessary that the last character ends up in only one "single" accepting state. Right?